# What is the meaning of 'gravy' in this sentence

Tags: meaning

There’s more of gravy than of grave about you, whatever you are!

Because, said Scrooge, a little thing affects them. A slight disorder of the stomach makes them cheats. You may be an undigested bit of beef, a blot of mustard, a crumb of cheese, a fragment of an underdone potato. There’s more of gravy than of grave about you, whatever you are!

Comment: This is a play on words, since *grave* and *gravy* sound similar. It is the ordinary definition of *[gravy](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/gravy)*.

Comment: The apparation is being explained away as the result of some indigestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrooge suspects that the ghost is just a dream. Dreams were thought to be affected by what was eaten directly before sleeping.

The statement is a play on words: he suggests that the ghost is more of the nature of gravy (a type food) than the grave (the spirit of a dead person).